# Android MedioPlay How to play http or rtsp stream?

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I'm trying used mediaplay play http or rtsp protocol uri from server, when I play the

address as http://****.wma or *.mp3 ,it can working,but I tryed played the address as

"http://qr.fm.qq.com/qqradio?qqradio",it didn't working.

and also I'trying used VideoView play rstp protocol uri from server,when I play the adress as

“rstp：//***.sdp”,it can working ,but I tryed play the adress as "rtsp://vs1.thmz.com/radio31"

,it didn't working.

Anybody help me and tell me how

Answer (score 1):

These are live streams, not static files, so, while it may play back some .wma and .mp3 content - these live streams are not defined like that.

Are you sure the first stream link is valid? After a quick scan with nmap, it seems you may need to be in china to connect to this feed (qq.com Registrant Country Code - CN) I get 1000 scanned ports all filtered, usually means a firewall blocking specific geographic regions.

rtsp://vs1.thmz.com/radio31 -> This is a Windows Media Audio stream, using WMA2 codec, delivered via RTSP, which according to the Android Supported Media Formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html - is NOT supported.